# Query String in link of html email becoming malformed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-email, email-client

I've got a very odd issue occurring.  An html email that gives a link to track a package appears exactly as prepared and as expected, but for some users, it strips the equals sign and removes some characters of the query string:

PHP Code:

```
$url = 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=' . $tracking;
$url_encoded = htmlentities($url);
$note .= '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;">Fedex Tracking Number <a href="' . $url_encoded . '">' . $tracking . '</a></span>' . 
                    '<br><br>' . $url_encoded;
```

Here is what I see when looking at the email markup in Gmail, both on desktop and mobile device:

```
    <blockquote>
    <p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px">Fedex Tracking Number 
            <a href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=123456789012" 
                style="color:#505050;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" 
                target="_blank">123456789012</a>
         </span>
         <br>
         <br>
         <a href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=123456789012" 
            target="_blank">https://www.fedex.com/<wbr>fedextrack/?tracknumbers=<wbr>123456789012</a></p>
</blockquote>
```

Here is what some other people see when looking at the email markup:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px">Fedex Tracking Number 
          <a href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers%203456789012" 
            style="color:#505050;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" 
             target="_blank">123456789012</a>
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers" 
          target="_blank">https://www.fedex.com/<wbr>fedextrack/?tracknumbers</a> 3456789012
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

So it seems that whatever is parsing the email for viewing has an issue with the question mark and equals sign of the link's query string.  It's formatting it differently.

FYI, I'm using the simple 'add_order_note' function of the Woocommerce wordpress plugin...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the users experiencing this problem using email that goes through additional filtering? I've seen stuff like that sending email in to corporate networks where email is being heavily filtered, HTML can be randomly stripped off or broken in all sorts of ways.

I doubt anyone will be able to answer this definitely unless you can give more detail about the users that are experiencing the problem - what networks they are on, and what email clients they are using.

Comment: `=XX` (XX being hex digits) has special meaning in emails encoded in a certain way. You're probably neglecting to declare your email's encoding, and this is why different clients render it in different ways.

Comment: What @NiettheDarkAbsol is referring to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted_printable

Comment: I think you guys are all correct.  Inspecting the WooCommerce classes lead me to believe that only the "content-type" is set, and no encoding.  But it does have a filter hook, 'woocommerce_email_headers', that I have hooked into and appended a "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" to, so hopefully it is resolved.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think you should post your comment as an answer here, because as it seems to me this question has been resolved

Comment: Yes, if @NiettheDarkAbsol does so I will set to accepted answer. Will that help?

Comment: I've also found an issue with `<wbr>`, and can see that might be an issue here, and suggest using &#x200b; (zero width space) as a better equivalent - but needs to have the right encoding otherwise it might not be interpreted properly.